# why i can't access IPackageFragmentRoot?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

I'll try to develop some plugins.
so, I'm studying to plugins and listeners.
and I try to develop examples using listener and javamodel.
However, when I access to IPackageFragmentRoot element, it is not doing what I want.
so, I debugged it. then, I see IJavaProject element is not open! However I still can access to this project in eclipse.

what's wrong in my code? and how can I access in IPackageFragmentRoot?

These are examples for not open states.

[image: project]

[image: pacakage]

This is code snippet. currentProject is IProject that i selected in package explorer.

```
if (currentProject != null) {
    try {
        currentProject.open(new NullProgressMonitor());
    } catch (CoreException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    IJavaProject javaProject = JavaCore.create(currentProject);
    ProjectTreeNode root = createTreeNode(javaProject.getElementName());
    IPackageFragmentRoot srcFolder = javaProject.getPackageFragmentRoot("src");
    root = getContents(srcFolder, root);
    setInput(root);
}
```

**ADD**

I imported some projects in new workspace.

[image]

Is this wrong way??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using 'Run as Eclipse Application' to run and test your plugin.

When you run the plugin Eclipse starts a completely new instance of Eclipse with a new workspace. None of your existing code is present in this workspace. You must create new projects containing the projects you want to test with in this new workspace.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but i have another question. so, i'll update my question. Can you help me?

Comment: I can't tell from what you have shown. What happens when you debug your plugin? Are you getting the `IProject`? Are you getting the `IJavaProject`?

Comment: hm..... thank you for your answer. I found my error and got a solution.